# Error Handling for solution on sorting on protected Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

On a protected user form (table with data) I have found a possibility to allow sorting protected cells by unprotecting the header row when selected (if...then) and protecting the sheet whenever another cell(s) is selected (else). So now, when clicking the header row and clicking the filter symbol, users can sort, because in this moment the file is unprotected.

Now, there is one problem remaining: when users select data in the databodyrange (or any other cell that is not in header row (here: row 11)) and then directly click on the filter symbol in the header row for sorting, they have activated cells that cause the sheet to protect (Else) and to unprotect (If...then) at the same time.

So the code itsself works fine. What I struggle with is writing an error handling, that for example on error selects a cell in the header row and continues to run the macro in all funcionality + doesn't disturb the user.

What is an easy Error Handling for the following code?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Target.Worksheet
    If (Target.Row = 11) Then    'Row 11 is the tables header's row
       With Ws
       .Unprotect ""
       End With
    Else
        With Ws
        .EnableAutoFilter = True
        .EnableOutlining = True
        .Protect "", contents:=True, UserInterfaceonly:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks - and really just an error handling is looked for. No other workaround!

Comment: I don't think you are using the term "error handling" correctly. "Error" means a run-time error. I think you use "error" to refer to an "incorrect" action taken by the user (clicking sort when they active cell is not in the header row).

Comment: Yes that is exactly the case! I am relatively new to VBA, so I hope not to confuse any more terms here. 

How can I achieve, that the user gets no "error"-message for selecting "incorrect" cells and the code runs without problems?

eg. on "incorrect" action (=selection) change selection to a cell of the header row and run the code correctly (=unprotect sheet) and being able to sort without being interupted.

Comment: The difficulty is that there is no "OnSort" event that you can trap in VBA, and you can't sort data in a listobject if the listobject range is protected. Your options are to add a "Sort" button that the user must click if they want to sort, leave the sheet unprotected, or "manufacture" an OnSort event.

Comment: I agree, I have thought through all the same points. But there is the possibility of my concept above, which unprotects the sheet only, if the header row is seleted. In the header row are the filters, so its kind of a solution. I solved my issue with On Error Resume Next. I will post my own answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my own issue using On Error Resume Next. It is not super elegant, but this way users are able to "sort on a protected sheet with locked cells".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Target.Worksheet
On Error Resume Next
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
Application.Undo
MsgBox "Please select a cell in the header row, before sorting or  filtering."
End If
   If (Target.Row = 11) Then
   With Ws
   .Unprotect ""
   End With
Else
    With Ws
    .EnableAutoFilter = True
    .EnableOutlining = True
    .Protect "", contents:=True, UserInterfaceonly:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowSorting:=True
    End With
End If
End Sub
```